# How to echo #! and \n over SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I would like to create a file on a remote host, so I do

```
A=test
ssh localhost "echo -e \"\#\!/bin/sh -e\n $A\" > /tmp/test"
```

but then I get

```
\#\!/bin/sh -e
 test
```

instead of

```
#!/bin/sh -e
test
```

If I remove the escapes from `#!` then they are interpreted and fails.

**Question**

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the quoting nightmare by feeding the script to a remote `cat` on stdin.

```
A=test
ssh localhost 'cat > /tmp/test' <<SCRIPT
#!/bin/sh -e
$A
SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
$ A=test
$ ssh localhost 'echo -e "#!/bin/sh -e\n'"$A"'" > /tmp/test'
Password:
$ cat /tmp/test 
#!/bin/sh -e
test
$
```

using single quotes around the `!` to avoid history expansion and double quotes around `$A` to allow variable expansion. The string is thus here the concatenation of three strings.

The quotes are paired like this:

```
'echo -e "#!/bin/sh -e\n'"$A"'" > /tmp/test'
<-----------------------><--><-------------> (first interpretation before ssh)
         <-------------------->              (second interpretation after ssh)
```

Comment: The single quites to the far left and right, do they belong together?

Comment: no they are not paired together. You have to read it like this: `'echo -e "#!/bin/sh -e\n'  "$A"   '" > /tmp/test'`